# Use of bind function in boost.asio server example

Tags: boost, boost-asio

In boost.asio [example of asynchronous UDP server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html) we can find next code:

```
  void start_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
..........
void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
```

According to specification of [basic_datagram_socket::async_receive_from](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from/overload1.html) function, its prototype is

```
template<
    typename MutableBufferSequence,
    typename ReadToken = DEFAULT>
DEDUCED async_receive_from(
    const MutableBufferSequence & buffers,
    endpoint_type & sender_endpoint,
    ReadToken && token = DEFAULT);
```

when token may be a function with prototype

```
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
  std::size_t bytes_transferred // Number of bytes received.
);
```

I do not understand two things (at least)

1. How `bind` work here? It accept `handle_receive` pointer, `udp_server` object (what for?) and two placeholders. How does it turn to function that is called at the end of asynchronous call and get context varibles?
2. How does `handle_receive` function access a `recv_buffer_` which is an argument of `async_receive_from` function but not of `handle_receive`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind returns a bound function object. There's extensive documentation about how it works and why you'd use it:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html
- also see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

---

1. `udp_server` object (what for?)

(Non-static) member functions take an implicit `this` pointer argument to the class  instance (object). So a 2-argument non-static member function void X::foo(int,int) const`takes 3 arguments:`X const*, int, int`.

2. How does handle_receive function access a recv_buffer_ which is an argument of async_receive_from function but not of handle_receive?

`recv_buffer_` is a data member of the same class (`udp_server`), so in `handle_receive` it is implicitly accessing it as `this->recv_buffer_`. This is very elementary C++, so I recommend maybe reading a good introduction or book if this is new for you.